# Can we further analyse groups after paired t test?

Tags: t-test

I am conducting a one group pre test post test study. If I would like to further analyse the groups (male/female, urban/rural, age categories)-should I do ?independent T test analyses or is there another way to it?

Comment: I think this depends on what you exactly want to do, do you just want an idea about the differences in means between for example males an females? Then a (paired) t-test sounds fine (when all assumptions are met of course), if you want to see for example how age influences the probability of living in a rural or urban place, you can look into regression analyses, sometimes even just some exploratory analysis (histograms, boxplots, ...) to show the distribution of gender across ages can be fine already. So it really depends on what you want.

Comment: @Mathemagician777 This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: I'll repost it as an answer, thanks :)

Comment: @mathemagician777 So I would like to see compare the means pre test vs post test (meaning did the males performed better than females, or did those in urban setting scored better than those in the rural setting)?

Comment: I am using SPSS. Should I do a paired t test (pre test post test) one by one after I have separated them by their groups?

Answer (score 1):

It is still a bit vague to me what you exactly want to do, but here are a few options:

- If you want to compare the scores of people before and after they take a test (so here you look at the effect of a test), then you can indeed look at a paired t-test.
- If you want to see if the difference in scores for pre test vs post test is different between two groups,  you can for example compare the difference in scores for the males with those from the females using a t-test (not a paired one since these scores are not linked now)

Just as an extra: this experiment, including the need to see the interaction between the effect of pre vs post test and the effect of the gender of the participant, might also be nice to investigated using a regression model, of course if you are interested in these quantities.